# How Do I Get The First Day Of The Months Number In PHP?

Tags: php, date

I know that I can use `date("w");` to get a number 0-6 depending on what day it is, but how would I do this to see what day the first day in the current month is? For example, this month March 1st was a Wednesday, so it should return a 3 for Wednesday.

I tried using this `date("w", "Y-m-01")` but it just gives me the error

```
Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the day (eg. "Wednesday") that is first in the current month:

```
echo date('l',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1));
```

..I suspect this was more useful to OP, hence the accept, but in fact it can be modified to meet the exact requirements of the question (number - eg "3") with:

```
echo date('N',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$month_start = strtotime('first day of this month', time());

//first day name , month, year
echo date('D, m Y', $month_start).'<br/>';

//first day number (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2) etc , month, year
echo date('N, m Y', $month_start).'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```
$date = date("N", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), 1, date('Y')));

echo $date;
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do it with class DateTime

```
echo (new DateTime('first day of this month'))->format('jS, F Y');

echo (new DateTime('2017-03-17'))
  ->modify('first day of this month')
  ->format('jS, F Y');
```